# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id' - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, csv, odoo, odoo-9

I've migrated a module which can create `stock.inventory` movements, by uploading csv's.

It's functioning quite good, but sometimes, when I upload certain csv's, it throws me this error:

```
Odoo

Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 648, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 685, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 321, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 314, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 964, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 514, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 892, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 880, in _call_kw
return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 421, in old_api
result = new_api(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 425, in new_api
result = [method(rec, *args, **kwargs) for rec in self]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/custom_addons/stock_inventory_import/wizard/import_inventory.py", line 85, in action_import
val['location_id'] = prod_location.id
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

The code is this:

```
@api.one
def action_import(self):
    """Load Inventory data from the CSV file."""
    ctx = self._context
    stloc_obj = self.env['stock.location']
    inventory_obj = self.env['stock.inventory']
    inv_imporline_obj = self.env['stock.inventory.import.line']
    product_obj = self.env['product.product']
    if 'active_id' in ctx:
        inventory = inventory_obj.browse(ctx['active_id'])
    if not self.data:
        raise exceptions.Warning(_("You need to select a file!"))
    # Decode the file data
    data = base64.b64decode(self.data)
    file_input = cStringIO.StringIO(data)
    file_input.seek(0)
    location = self.location
    reader_info = []
    if self.delimeter:
        delimeter = str(self.delimeter)
    else:
        delimeter = ','
    reader = csv.reader(file_input, delimiter=delimeter,
                        lineterminator='\r\n')
    try:
        reader_info.extend(reader)
    except Exception:
        raise exceptions.Warning(_("Not a valid file!"))
    keys = reader_info[0]
    # check if keys exist
    if not isinstance(keys, list) or ('code' not in keys or
                                      'quantity' not in keys):
        raise exceptions.Warning(
            _("Not 'code' or 'quantity' keys found"))
    del reader_info[0]
    values = {}
    actual_date = fields.Date.today()
    inv_name = self.name + ' - ' + actual_date
    inventory.write({'name': inv_name,
                     'date': fields.Datetime.now(),
                     'imported': True, 'state': 'confirm'})
    for i in range(len(reader_info)):
        val = {}
        field = reader_info[i]
        values = dict(zip(keys, field))
        prod_location = location.id
        if 'location' in values and values['location']:
            locat_lst = stloc_obj.search([('name', '=',
                                           values['location'])])
            if locat_lst:
                prod_location = locat_lst[0]
        prod_lst = product_obj.search([('default_code', '=',
                                        values['code'])])
        if prod_lst:
            val['product'] = prod_lst[0].id
        if 'lot' in values and values['lot']:
            val['lot'] = values['lot']
        val['code'] = values['code']
        val['quantity'] = values['quantity']
        val['location_id'] = prod_location.id
        val['inventory_id'] = inventory.id
        val['fail'] = True
        val['fail_reason'] = _('No processed')
        inv_imporline_obj.create(val)
```

And the csv's look like this:

```
id       product_id     reference                   code    combinacion avanzadastock   location                            quantity    qty
2780    Piloto trasero  Recambio Ecológico Original M0002780                            gsx 600 f 600 1988-1991/4316/A8I    1
```

This error appears from time to time, often it just works without problems, but some other times throws this error.

It is exactly on `location` column.

I have csv's with more than 5k items, so it's difficult for me to track the error.

Is this csv related? Or it is a matter of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is your logic

```
prod_location = location.id
```

Then the following if statement is never entered, and you move to

```
val['location_id'] = prod_location.id
```

And the error is thrown

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 thank you very much, excuse me, please, do You know a workaround for this? I mean, seems like the objects don't match right?

Comment: I do not know this library you are using, sorry. Just `prod_location` is getting set to an integer. You have to fix the if statement to get `prod_location = locat_lst[0]` to always run

Comment: Thank You very much, if it goes wrong I'll open a new question, Thank You again!

Answer (score 1):

Yes correct. Some location don't exist on the system. That's it throws error. To avoid such error, you can use following trick.

```
prod_location = self.location and self.location.id or False
```

Means if system has location then *prod_location* variable set value with *id* of location otherwise *False*

NOTE:

In model declaration, *location_id* field set with required=False otherwise you can not create record with *location_id=False* It will give you *integrity error.*

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was the csv content

Because some locations don't exist on the system, then it throws out that error.

So, need to check for locations that do exist before continuing with the process.

Thank You.